# Guess-Who? Best Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm making a program that imitates the guess-who game where questions are asked in order to determine who the secret person is.

I'm just kind of stuck on how to categorize my questions in a way that it will be the most efficient, the characters have 6 different attributes, Shirt, Hair, Eye, Smiling, Hair, Glasses.

[image]

I already wrote a program to this but my decision tree was so inefficient that it asked around 10-30 questions. My aim is to find an algorithm thats between 6-10 questions.

If it helps I'll provide the my old tree to show you what I'm talking about but I'm gonna make a new one based on what you guys think.

```
if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.eyeIsColor(Color.HAZEL) &&
    g.isSmiling() && g.shirtIsColor(Color.GREEN) &&
    g.isWearingGlasses())
    a = "Emily";

if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.GREEN)) {
    if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
        a = "Alice";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.GREEN))
        a = "Frank";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.isWearingGlasses())
        a = "Bob";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN))
        a = "Dave"; // this might be an error for other brown hair
    else
        a = "Isabelle";
}
// NULL IT WAS EMILY FALSE

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.RED)) {
    if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.GREEN))
        a = "Philip";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE) && !g.isSmiling())
        a = "Wendy";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE) && g.isWearingGlasses()) 
        a = "Mallie";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
        a = "Nick";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.isWearingHat())
        a = "Robert";
    else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.isSmiling())
        a = "Quinn";
}



else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLACK) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.BLUE)) {
    if (!g.isSmiling())
        a = "Carol";
    else if (g.isWearingHat())
        a = "Gertrude";
    else
        a = "Olivia";
}


else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
    a = "Tucker";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN) && g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN))
    a = "Zander";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLOND) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.RED))
    a = "Henry";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLOND) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.BLUE))
    a = "Jack";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLACK) && g.eyeIsColor(Color.HAZEL))
    a = "Karen";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLACK) && g.isWearingHat())
    a = "Xavier";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BLACK))
    a = "Ursula";

else if (g.hairIsColor(Color.RED) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.GREEN))
    a = "Yasmine";

else if (g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
    a = "Larry";

else if (g.isWearingHat())
    a = "Sarah";

else if (g.isSmiling())
    a = "Victor";

return a;
```

Comment: I think you should try out Drools

Comment: Instead of hard code this, I would use a list of object i.e. `Person `data structures. This would make it easier to efficiently choose the next question. i.e. you want the question which has a 50/50 chance of a yes/now answer.

Comment: There is a Person class that has all the people and their attributes defined but I can't access them. The goal is for this class to decide who they are by the attributes

Comment: @kocko Not sure what the person marking this homework will say. lol.

Comment: @Panthy in that case, you would need to explain the requirements as that's not how you play Guess-Who.  You play by seeing all the possible people by picture, i.e. you have access to all their attributes and you have to select the best question from those remaining. You know the answer there there is only one possibility left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a probability problem : *solving a problem using binary questions*

The most efficient way to answer a problem is to ask a question that is the closest of 50%/50% probability.
For example if there is half girls and half men statistically asking the question "Is it a man?" is the better choice possible.

So you might want for **each** questions to test all questions possible and find the one closest to 50/50 with the remaining people.

[I've found a good article that might help you](http://www.r-bloggers.com/want-to-win-to-guess-who-have-an-institutional-neural-network-approach/)

Comment: I've added an article too my answer that might help you

Comment: if it is possible can i speak to you on a chat?

Comment: You should not only try to reach the 50/50 balance, but also look forward and ask questions that if answered will again produce the possibility of asking a 50/50 (or close) questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from this diagram exactly how your were asking the questions and getting the data. You're mainly showing which conditions have to be true rather than what process you used to ascertain these values.

A solution might be to check out of the remaining answers available after each question, see which variable is the most likely to be true and ask if it is. For example, in the initial set size, asking "Is the person smiling?" would eliminate four choices if it were true, but could potentially eliminate much more if it weren't true. Another way might be to check which answer might half the current dataset most efficiently e.g. "Does the person wear glasses" would eliminate half of the answers. In the next question it could be that checking if the person has blue eyes would eliminate half of what remains. This would be less efficient for some people, but generally speaking more efficient overall (if you half the results each time on average you'd get the answer in about five~six questions on average).

Comment: The strategy of asking 90%/10% question is a really bad one. (see article add to my answer for explanations)

Answer (score 0):

What can do is to map your table in the source code. There are many ways to do that. I will use a simple object arrays

First we define a data structure

```
Object[] person = new Object {"Alice", Color.BROWN, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FAlSE};
```

We see that under each indexes we represent some attribute of Alice 
 0 - Name
 1 - Hair
 2 - Shirt
 3 - Eyes
 4 - Glasses
 5 - Smiling 
 6 - Hat

If we stick to this order we can compare only the values from person with values from our guesses.

```
Object[] guess = Object[] {Color.BROWN, COLOR.RED, Color.HAZE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE.Boolean.TRUE};
```

So what we should do is to create our model where we add the persons.

```
  List<Object[]> model = createModel(); //This method add preson into list

  for(Object[] person: model) {

     for(int i = 1; i < person.length; i++) {
          if(person[i].equals[gues[i]) {
            //We share some attributes 

            if(i == person.length -1) {
              return person[0]; //We report the name 
            }
         }  else {
            break; /We break and go to another person from model. 
         }
     }
  }
```

In the next phase you can replace the object array with a proper class implementation.